# How can I connect with database existing in my sdcard using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, database, cordova, phonegap-plugins

There  is a db file in my sdcard and i want to connect with it through phonegap. How can i do this?

```
var db = window.openDatabase("sdcard/1_user.db", "1.0", "db", 0);
```

Every time it is creating a new db instead of connecting a previous one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. Database selection just goes by name which is saved on the internal memory. No way to select a file. Check the W3 database with the [Web SQL standard.](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)

You can import and export a JSON file in to your database though. Check out this [script](https://gist.github.com/teusinkorg/5892402) of mine to do that.

Comment: is it possible , if my .db file is not in sdcard, its in my internal memory then i can connect it? B'cause according to phonegap docs , window.openDatabase creates a db and also it connects to db which is already existing  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: That might be true,  but the code still does not work that way.  It should be possible to access the dB file,  but you will have to write the code to access it yourself and thus write your own interperter.